# How to resolve promise inside Angular $timeout

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

With callbacks, I wrap the callback in an Angular $timeout block so that it updates the UI.

```
function makeServerRequest(callback) {
  $timeout(callback);
}

makeServerRequest((response) => {
  $scope.updateUI();
})
```

This operates within the Angular digest cycle, and the UI gets updated.

However, this doesn't work:

```
function makeServerRequest() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $timeout(() => {
      resolve();
    });
  })
}

makeServerRequest().then(() => {
  $scope.updateUI();
})
```

In this case, it seems like the resolve happens, and *then* `$scope.updateUI();` is called after the timeout.

How can I wrap `resolve` inside a timeout, so that the outside .then is called inside a timeout?

Comment: It is a good idea to use `$q` instead of native promises which has handlers that will be evaluated during a digest cycle.

Comment: Best practice is to avoid ES6 promises. Or if coming from a 3rd party library, convert them to AngularJS promises with [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a AngularJS promise from a callback-based API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43134613/5535245).

Comment: @georgeawg does the sole reason for this best practice have to do with digest cycles?

Comment: AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc. AngularJS $q promises are integrated with the framework execution context.

Answer (score 1):

Native Promise doesn't trigger a digest, it should be triggered manually in this case:

```
makeServerRequest().then(() => {
  $scope.updateUI();
  $scope.$apply()
})
```

And $timeout already returns a promise ($q promise, which is digest-friendly).  So there's no need to create a new one, especially a native one.

It can be:

```
function makeServerRequest() {
  return $timeout(angular.noop, 100);
}

makeServerRequest().then(...);
```

Comment: So the key then is just to return a $timeout object?

Comment: Yes. setTimeout needs to be promisified to become a promise. $timeout doesn't need that. It's unclear why you use a timeout in makeServerRequest, but I assume you emulate it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a $q promise from the server request API:

```
function makeServerRequest() {
  return $q((resolve, reject) => {
     var callback = resolve;
     ServerRequest(callback);
  });  
}

makeServerRequest().then(() => {
  $scope.updateUI();
})
```

There is no need to use `$timeout` as the $q Service is integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q constructor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#-q-constructor).