# Angularjs 1.5 component modal with callback function not updating binding

Tags: angularjs, callback

[How to create a AngularJS promise from a callback-based API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43121872/how-to-create-a-angularjs-promise-from-a-callback-based-api)

[Why are Callbacks from Promise `.then` Methods an Anti-Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660881/why-are-callbacks-from-promise-then-methods-an-anti-pattern)

I have an Angularjs 1.5 modal component as below. The modal opens and on render event it calls a function outside of the angular app with a callback function contained in this component. This outside function initiates a install process which then periodically calls another function reportbackStatus which calls the callback and returns the message.

The issue I am having is the binding is not being updated in the template on each callback function call. The console.log is executed and i can see the message in the console. The binding is initially updated with 'starting process' so binding is correct

```
<span ng-bind="$ctrl.messages[$ctrl.messages.length - 1]"></span>
```

I tried wrapping code in scope.apply function as below but i get [Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog) issue. Only when all is completed is the last message shown from the final callback call.

is this the correct way to handle multiple callbacks and updating bindings

```
  angular.module('components')
  .component('testModal', {
    bindings:{
      modalInstance: '<',
      resolve: '=',
      dismiss: '&',
      close: '&'
    },
    controller: TestController,
    templateUrl: 'scripts/components/TestModal.html'
});

TestController.$inject = ['$scope'];
function TestController($scope) {
  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.$onInit = function(){
    ctrl.messages = [];
    ctrl.messages.push('starting process');
  };

  ctrl.modalInstance.rendered.then(function(){
    CallVanillaJSFunction(callback); 
  });

  function callback(message){
    ctrl.messages.push(message);
    console.log(ctrl.messages[ctrl.messages.length - 1]);
    CheckScopeBeforeApply();
  }

  function CheckScopeBeforeApply() {
    if(!$scope.$$phase) {
      $scope.$apply();
      console.log('scope applied');
    }
  };

}
```

Vanilla Function

```
var globalCallback;

function CallVanillaJSFunction(callback){
    globalCallback = callback;
    initiateprocess();  
}

function reportbackStatus(message){
   globalCallback(message);
}
```

The global callback function can be called multiple times and the angular application does not know how many times it will be called.